# How return and use autoincremented id in h2 script

Tags: sql, h2

I'm trying to make in-memory tests for my socNetwork and I would make reusable script for table populating.
This listing doesn't works. Please, help me.

```
set @id1 = 0;

INSERT INTO accounts (firstName, lastName) OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @id1
VALUES ('Adolph', 'Putiin') ;

INSERT INTO phones (number, account_id)
VALUES ('+77777777777', @id1);
```

Error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "


INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) (OUTPUT[*] INSERTED.ID INTO @ID1)
VALUES ('Adolph', 'Putiin') "; expected "(, WITH, SELECT, TABLE, VALUES"
Syntax error in SQL statement "
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? If it's SQL Server, after your insert, you can use `@@IDENTITY` to capture the value of the last inserted IDENTITY value: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I use H2 database